# Regex Pattern for filtering multiline data for REST API

Tags: python, regex, rest, asa

Migrating ASAs from ASDM to FMC including access policy. One of the steps to complete the project is to migrate network/service objects, their groups to FMC. Planning to create objects by filtering ASA objects (from ASA configuration) with regex and running python script on REST API. Now the issue which I currently have is a lot of data to move across to FMC, over 3000 lines.

Currently trying to come up with a regex pattern that would filter multiline strings and match data for REST API. Using regex101 for this task. With current regex pattern I am matching data for first two lines only. One of the other problems I came across was that not all lines include 'destination eq' after which regex is matching 'port_no'.

Would someone be able to assist with regex expression? As per current regex expression want to match data that comes after 'object-group service', 'service-object' and 'destination eq' OR when 'destination eq' is not present?

Thanks

Regex expression:

```
object-group service (?P<name>.+)(?:\n |.)service-object (?P<protocol>.+) destination eq (?P<port_no>\d{0,5} |\w{0,10}.+)\n
```

Data to filter:

```
object-group service DM_INLINE_SERVICE_8
 service-object tcp destination eq ldap
 service-object udp destination eq syslog
 service-object object kerberos5-tcp
 service-object object kerberos5-udp
 service-object object ldap-udp
 service-object udp destination eq domain
 service-object object ldap-gcs
 service-object object TCP_3268
 service-object object TCP_3269
 service-object object TCP_445
 service-object tcp-udp destination eq domain
 service-object tcp destination eq ldaps
 service-object udp destination eq ntp
 service-object object TCP_464
object-group network DM_INLINE_NETWORK_13
 network-object object IN_V030_197_memcache_01
 network-object object IN_V030_198_memcache_02
```

Comment: Do you mean like this? https://regex101.com/r/A5H9EY/1 Or if you want to match all that follows service-object https://regex101.com/r/CJcHpv/1

Answer (score 0):

If you want to match data that comes after 'object-group service', 'service-object' and 'destination eq' you might use an [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) to match either `object-group service` or `service-object` and an optional non capturing group for `destination eq`.

```
^\s*(?:object-group service|service-object) (.+?)(?: destination eq (\w+))?$
```

In parts

- `^` Start of string
- `\s*` Match 0+ whitespace chars
- `(?:object-group service|service-object)` Match 1 of the options
- `(.+?)` Match space and capture in **group 1** matching any char non greedy
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `destination eq (\w+)` Match space and destination eq and capture 1+ word chars in **group 2**
- `)?` Close group and make it optional
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/CJcHpv/1/)

Comment: Trying to match all lines that are after object-group, finishing with the last entry of object-group line. In this scenario it would be 'service-object object TCP_464'. The initial regex pattern matches first two lines (object-group and service-object) as per [Example](https://regex101.com/r/CJcHpv/3).

Now another challenge is to match data that comes after service-object (?P<protocol>) when the string 'destination eq' is not present.

Comment: it did not, still getting used to stack overflow messaging system this being my first post.

Comment: @Labanavis Do you mean like this? https://regex101.com/r/amN0Vt/1

Comment: Figured out regex pattern as per https://regex101.com/r/amN0Vt/2
Thanks for your assistance